# Using Accelerate vDSP_FFT for non log2(N) to replicate matlab fft()

Tags: ios, matlab, fft, fftw, accelerate-framework

I am trying to calculate an the DFT of an audio sample. I run into problems when I attempt to calculate the fft using non log2(N) when N is the number of sample pieces. I am currently using vdsp_fft_zripD(). In the solution is basically what I have. [FFT using Accelerate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21893481/hilbert-transform-analytical-signal-using-apples-accelerate-framework). I need to replicate the FFT values from Matlab.

I know that Matlab uses FFTW3 library but would like to avoid using it if possible because I am writing an ios app using swift. I've created a wrapper for the vDSP in obj-c to make it a little easier. It does compute values correctly for all log2(N). I tried padding the input array with zeroes at the end but I don't get the correct results towards the end.

Comment: What value of N?  What differences are you seeing?

Comment: So it turns out I've been overthinking the problem. I was seeing differences in the non abs() value version. I also realize that the magnitude would not be the same however the proportions did turn out the same for the frequencies. I still don't know exactly how Matlab gets the values for the untrimmed array but it is not important for me anymore.